# Not shifting the adverbial of time in reported speech

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity, time

I know that generally, in reported speech e.g. tomorrow shifts to "the following day". But I also know that in some cases it can remain, e.g:

> He said he would do that tomorrow.

That one should be correct if I say that on the same day (tomorrow has not begun) but he e.g. changed his mind and I know this is not gonna happen.

But can it be also with another expression of future?

> He said he was coming home the next week.

Can it be correct? E.g. he says that and dies the same day in the car accident. So would be correct to  keep "next week" in this reported speech, because it is still the future?

Comment: _the next day_ and _the week after_ are perhaps what you are looking for

Comment: I am asking whether the construction is possible when the content of reported speech is still a future (has not happened yet), not sure how your comment relates to that.

Comment: It looks correct to me. My suggestions could be used regardless of time they were said and regardless of when the event would actually happen

Comment: @mplungjan is correct. Although I would use "the following week" instead of "the week after".

Comment: I would be happier with "would be coming home the next week* or possibly *would come home the next week*, but that doesn't affect the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

The same rules applies to other time adverbials as applies to *tomorrow*:

> *Rule 1*: If the time referred to is still in the future, you don't need to change the adverbial.
>
> *Rule 2*: If the time referred to has started but not finished, change the adverbial (usually to include *this*).
>
> *Rule 3*: If the time referred to has finished, change the adverbial (usually to include the definite article).

Here are two examples. A. Imagine a son telling his mother on Friday: "*I'm coming home tomorrow!*" (Saturday) and the mother reporting this to her husband.

She tells her husband on Friday: *Rule 1* - "Mark said he's coming home tomorrow!"

She tells her husband early on Saturday: *Rule 2* - "Mark said he's coming home today!"

She tells her husband a month later. (Her son had changed his mind on Friday evening): *Rule 3* - "Mark said he was coming home the next day."

B. Imagine Mark says to his girlfriend Susan in 2012: "Let's get married next year!" and Susan reports this to her parents.

She tells her parents in 2012: *Rule 1* - "Mark suggested that we get married next year."

She tells her parents at the beginning of 2012: *Rule 2* - "Mark suggested that we get married this year."

She tells her parents many years later: *Rule 3* - "Mark suggested that we got married the following year (but then he met someone else!)"

Comment: I cried a little reading the last sentence :*( I'm sure Susan will find a better man in the year(s) to come!

Comment: @Mary-Lou. Well, at least she didn't die as in the OP's example!

Comment: In your final example *get* should not be backshifted: it's a subjunctive clause which elicits the bare infinitive form.

Comment: @StoneyB. The backshift sounds fine to me, a British native speaker. I suspect that it is more likely to trouble American native speakers.

Comment: I understand that BE doesn't demand the "mandative subjunctive", but that's really only an issue with *be* and with 3d-person-singular forms, and *that we **got*** implies an event prior to the suggestion: "My sister suggested that we got married in 1989, but I corrected her." The ordinary evasion of subjunctive is a construction with *should*: "Mark suggested that we should get married the following year". You certainly would not backshift that to "Mark suggested that we should have got married ...*.

Comment: Using the verb _suggest_ in my example muddied the waters. It would have been better to have written: _Mark told me that he wanted to get married the following year._

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Shoe's analysis as regards your first example:

> He said he would do that tomorrow.

This refers to whichever day is "tomorrow" *at the time **you** make the statement*, and *irrespective of the day on which "he said" it*. For example:
"He" said it on Monday; you spoke the sentence on Thursday = He will be "doing it" on Friday.

As regards your second example:

> He said he was coming home the next week.

Because of the word "the" in "*the* next week", I understand this to be referring to the week immediately following *the week in which **he** said that*, *irrespective of when you made the statement*. For example:
"He" said it in week 1; he [then] expected to be coming home in week 2; *you* spoke the sentence in week 3 or later.

This could alternatively, and perhaps slightly more clearly, be re-phrased as:

> He said he was coming home the *following* week.

The use of the word *following* instead of *next* helps to remove any ambiguity that "next" may refer to "next week" relative to when ***you*** made the statement.

***But***, if you were to *omit* the word "the" in "*the* next week":

> He said he was coming home next week.

then the analysis would be the same as for your first example: "next week" would be relative to *the time **you** make the statement*, and *irrespective of when "he said" it*. For example:
"He" said it in week 1; you spoke the sentence in week 3 = He will be coming home in week 4.